# jQuery Mobile inset lists not adding margins as expected

Tags: jquery-mobile

I tried it on firefox, chrome, and mobile safari.  When I add data-inset="true" to lists it will correctly round the corners of the list, but it does not add the 1em margin on either side as it should.  I can't figure this out.  It even does it on a simple boilerplate page with nothing in it but the list.  eg:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="#">first</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">second</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

does not show correctly.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out.  To get this to work I just had to wrap the body contents in a <div> with data-role="content".  Works fine now.

Comment: please answer and/or close you own question, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. To get this to work I just had to wrap the body contents in a `<div>` with data-role="content". Works fine now.

Comment: i want to remove margin from left and right side how to do it?